# How to send dynamically value from javascript to hiddenfield

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a variable "place", which is changing dynamically (get diffrent values for some actions). Here JS code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
});
```

How to get this variable to asp.net(C#) in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('myHiddenField').value = place;
```

Just keep in mind that client IDs are dynamic in ASP.NET, unless you're using ASP.NET 4 and set ClientIDMode = "Static" on that hidden field.  So you may need to add something like this to your Page_Load:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript(this, "hiddenFieldIdSetter", "var hiddenFieldID = '"+ myHiddenField.ID +"';", true);
```

and then use the following javascript, instead:

```
document.getElementById(hiddenFieldID).value = place;
```